# Returning the outputs from a CloudFormation template with Boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to retrieve the list of outputs from a CloudFormation template using Boto. I see in the docs there's an object named `boto.cloudformation.stack.Output`.  But I think this is unimplemented functionality.  Is this currently possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do a `describe_stacks` call, it will return a list of Stack objects and each of those will have an `outputs` attribute which is a list of `Output` objects.

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yup! Thanks, Mitch.  I was looking at `list_stacks`.