# How to read the describe_stack Output attribute

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, stack, boto, aws-cloudformation

i have created a stack in cloudformatin and wants to get the output.
My code is:

```
c = a.describe_stacks('Stack_id') 
print c
```

Returns an object

```
<boto.cloudformation.stack.StackSummary object at 0x1901d10>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning the outputs from a CloudFormation template with Boto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163114/returning-the-outputs-from-a-cloudformation-template-with-boto)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The call to `describe_stacks` should return a list of `Stack` objects, not a single `StackSummary` object.  Let's just walk through a complete example to avoid confusion.

First, do something like this:

```
import boto.cloudformation
conn = boto.cloudformation.connect_to_region('us-west-2')  # or your favorite region
stacks = conn.describe_stacks('MyStackID')
if len(stacks) == 1:
    stack = stacks[0]
else:
    # Raise an exception or something because your stack isn't there
```

At this point the variable `stack` is a `Stack` object.  The outputs of the stack are available as the `outputs` attribute of `stack`.  This attribute will contain a list of `Output` objects which, in turn, have a `key`, `value`, and `description` attribute.  So, this would print all of the outputs:

```
for output in stack.outputs:
    print('%s=%s (%s)' % (output.key, output.value, output.description))
```